# Does JavaScript's reverse( ) always change the original variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, reverse

Let me explain:

```
function PalindromeTwo(str) {
  str = str.split('');
    var arr = [];
    str.forEach(function(it){
      if( (/[a-z]/i).test(it) ){
          arr.push(it);
        }
    })
    var reverseArr = arr.reverse();
    return reverseArr.join('').toUpperCase() === arr.join('').toUpperCase();
}

PalindromeTwo("hello, there");
```

In this example, it returns `true` when it should return `false` because the line `var reverseArr = arr.reverse()` reversed not just `reverseArr` but `arr`, i.e. the original variable, as well. Why is that?

Comment: Note, you could also just traverse the `str` array in backwards order with a `for` loop and then not have to reverse the resulting `arr`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the array in place. You can create a copy before reversing though by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
var copy = arr.slice();
copy.reverse();
```

Answer (score 5):

> Why is that?

Because the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.reverse) says so:

> The elements of the array are rearranged so as to reverse their order. The object is returned as the result of the call.